# Does anybody know what these codes mean, 'WyvernExchange' Smart Contract Codes?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, smart-contract-wallets, swaps

Does anybody know what these codes mean based on the smart contract of WyvernExchange?

In this atomicMatch function, there is address[14] addrs, <<-- what does this mean?

I think 14 means from addrs[0] to addrs[14]. but I have no idea how these addresses are connected with WHAT.

Is anybody letting me know how these addresses are related with?

Thank you

[image: WyvernExchange]

Answer (score 0):

It is a fixed size array

```
Type[N]
```

Means an array of `N` elements of type `Type`.

So `address[14]` is an array of 14 `address`es.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes.. I try to match every detail line to understand now. :)